# Put data into unequal bin sizes

Tags: r, dataset, binning

I'm new to **R** and want to utilize it to directly work with my data. My ultimate goal is to make a histogram / bar plot.

> Depth: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
>
> Percent: .4, .1, .5, .2, .1, .3, .9, .3, .2, .2, .8

I want to take the Depth vector and bin it into unequal chunks (0, 1-5, 6-8, 9-10), and take the Percent values and somehow sum them together for the matching chunks.

For example:

> 0 -> .4
>
> 1-5 -> 1.2
>
> 6-8 -> 1.4
>
> 9-10 -> 1.0

The actual data set goes into the thousands, and I feel **R** might be more suited for this then using C++ to group my data into a smaller table before letting R plot it.

I looked up how to use SPLIT and CUT, but I'm not quite sure how to utilize the data after I do cut it into ranges.  If I do "breaks" for a CUT, I don't know how to include the Zero initial value (corresponding to .4 in the example).

Any suggestions or approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track with `cut`:

```
dat <- data.frame(Depth = 0:10,
                  Percent = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8))

cuts <- cut(dat$Depth, breaks=c(0, 1, 6, 9, 11), right=FALSE)
```

Then you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(dat$Percent, list(cuts), sum)
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
aggregate(dat$Percent, 
          list(cut(dat$Depth, 
                   breaks=c(0, 1, 6, 9, 11), 
                   right=FALSE)),
          sum)
```

Comment: I'll try this, that's so simple and straightforward.

Comment: I just learned that you have to "checkmark" the correct answer on this forum. Thanks for your help! R is growing on me.